# how to get python installed path from command line

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd

I am trying to get the installed path of python?
Any idea how to get the python installed path from command line in windows. I don't want to set the environment variable?

Thanks,

Answer (score 92, accepted):

try opening up `cmd` and simply:

```
where python
```

By default, this searches your PATH for matches.  More precisely:

> Description:
>       Displays the location of files that match the search pattern.
>       By default, the search is done along the current directory and
>       in the paths specified by the PATH environment variable.

Most windows python installers modify your PATH so this should find what doing `python` at the CLI will call.

Comment: `where` works with windows?

Comment: @thefourtheye yes.  in *nix it's `which`.

Comment: Great! direct to the point

Comment: thank you where much I really tired looking for the alternative of which of Linx command and last I got where after 1 hour of search this is really what I say......

Comment: The nice thing about using "where" is that if you have more than 1 file with the same name in your path (which can lead to annoying issues) it will list all of them.

Answer (score 51):

Cross-platform solution using [`sys.executable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable)

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

---

> sys.**executable**
>
> A string giving the absolute path of the executable binary for the
>   Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can check registry by: 
`HKLM SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\${PYTHON_VERSION}\InstallPath`

or HKCU

Comment: HKCU worked for me: 
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Item -Path Registry::HKEY_Current_User\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.6-32\InstallPath